# Two layouts in one row

Tags: c#, alignment, xamarin.forms

In CSS two `divs` can be placed in one row using `float:left`.

How can this be achieved Xamarin.Forms?

The code I have so far:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        StackLayout sl2 = new StackLayout ();
        sl2.WidthRequest = 400;
        sl2.HeightRequest = 400;
        sl2.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        sl2.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        StackLayout sl3 = new StackLayout ();
        sl3.WidthRequest = 400;
        sl3.HeightRequest = 400;
        sl3.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        sl3.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout ();                
        sl.Children.Add(sl2);
        sl.Children.Add(sl3);

        ContentPage contentPage = new ContentPage ();
        contentPage.Content = sl;
        MainPage = contentPage;
    }
}
```

But I need the red and green layouts to be placed in the same row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `StackLayout.Orientation` property:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        StackLayout sl2 = new StackLayout ();
        sl2.WidthRequest = 400;
        sl2.HeightRequest = 400;
        sl2.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        sl2.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        StackLayout sl3 = new StackLayout ();
        sl3.WidthRequest = 400;
        sl3.HeightRequest = 400;
        sl3.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        sl3.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout (); 
        sl.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        sl.Children.Add(sl2);
        sl.Children.Add(sl3);

        ContentPage contentPage = new ContentPage ();
        contentPage.Content = sl;
        MainPage = contentPage;
    }
}
```